# Does a quadrangulation with minimum degree $3$ contain either a $(3,3)$ edge or a $(3,4)$ edge$?$

Tags: geometry, graph-theory, planar-graphs

A simple graph $G$ is a quadrangulation of the plane if  it can be embedded in
the plane in such a way that all faces are quadrangles. We say an edge $e=(uv)$ is an $(a,b)$-edge if the degrees of the two end-vertices, $u$ and $v$, are $a$ and $b$, respectively.

I am thinking about the following question: **Does a quadrangulation with minimum degree $3$ must contain either a $(3,3)$ edge or a $(3,4)$ edge?**

I know the discharging method might work, but I am not yet able to master it proficiently.

---

Here is my initial attempt: First, we set the charge of each vertex to be $d_G(v)-4$ and the charge of each face to be $0$. In this case, the total charge, as calculated, is -8.

Suppose that a quadrangulation does not contain (3,3) and (3,4) edges, and then apply the following rules:

**Rule 1**: Each vertex with a degree of 5 or higher redistributes its initial charge uniformly to each incident face.

**Rule 2**: Each face redistributes its charge uniformly to incident 3-degree vertex.

**Our  goal is to obtain the charge of each vertex and face be greater than or equal to 0 through charge transfer, and then derive a contradiction.**
However, it seems that the two rules above do not work. I haven't found any contradictions. I might need a more clever discharging method.

[image]

Perhaps there are other non-discharging methods. Or a counterexample can be founded.

Comment: How does a face redistribute its charge "to incident 3 vertex"? The face has by set-up four vertices, and how does one know any of those vertices are incident to exactly 3 edges? And do you mean to distribute the face charge evenly to any incident 3 vertices of the four vertices that the face has?

Comment: @coffeemath I'm sorry I didn't make it clear. What I meant is that if a face receives a positive charge, it is immediately distributed equally to the 3-degree vertices on its boundary. These rules are just rough initial ideas, and you don't have to be restricted by them.

Comment: @MishaLavrov This is a typo, I will correct them immediately.

Comment: @licheng OK so you say "What I meant is that if a face receives a positive charge, it is immediately distributed equally to the 3-degree vertices on its boundary." What happens if at some stage a face has positive charge but there are no 3-degree vertices on its boundary?

Comment: Under your condition( there are no 3-degree vertices on its boundary), Rule 2 will not be executed and we will do nothing. However, I wonder if it can be designed more clever. The positive charges of these faces can be transferred according to some other new rules to these vertices with degree 3 that still have negative charges.

Comment: licheng--- Well then those positive charges would *have* to be distributed to some other degree vertices. My question is about the case where there are no degree 3 vertices, not about the case where there are some degree 3 vertices but they all happen to have negative charge at that point. If there are no degree 3 vertices [regardless of their charge positive or negative] at that time, then you can either do nothing, or discharge somehow onto vertices *not* of degree 3.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144976/discussion-between-coffeemath-and-licheng).